# Как убрать нижнюю грань в materialize при нажатии на input

Tags: css, css3, materialize-css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столкунулся с такой проблемой: при нажатии на `<input type="text"/>` у этого инпута появляется нижняя бирюзовая грань. Я уже копался в стилях этого инпута, но ничего даже с таким цветом не нашёл. Как убрать этот стиль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, это свойство **border-bottom**. Чтобы убрать достаточно установить его значение на **none**